# How to remove space above two buttons '+' and '-'?

Tags: html, css, space

This is my link code:
https://jsfiddle.net/robocon321/Lnw198jp/9

```
<div class="change-button">
  <button class="increase">+</button>
  <input type="text" class="result" disabled="false" value="0"/>
  <button class="decrease">-</button>
</div>
```

. I tried to remove it by padding and margin but it don't working

Comment: Please add your CSS to your question.

Comment: Ok @zero298. I will remember it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set font-size of `.result` to `25px` instead of `45px`because your font-size is affecting. Or else just add `display: flex; align-content: flex-start;` to class `.change-button`

Comment: Oh. Can you explain more clearly about the reason what font-size affect the space on the 2 buttons ?

Comment: Right now the font size is of .result class is 45px and try to decrease the font-size of .result you can see the difference. The input size is fixed but font-size is more so the size of the input is changed. That's why it creates the space before the input. I hope you are clear with my explanation. If not then feel free to ask @ThanhNhậtNguyễn

Answer (score 3):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to `.decrease` & `.increase`

```
.increase{
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}

.decrease{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align:top;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/dn9j742s/1/

OR

Add `vertical-align:top;` to `.result`

```
.result{
  text-align:center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align:top;
  font-size: 45px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/dn9j742s/4/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I was trying to answer this question by giving negative top value using position relative, but found that its not good enough. Learnt something new!

Answer (score 3):

try to use `display: flex` from `change-button` class

```css
body{
  font-size:0px;
}
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border:0px solid black;
}

.increase{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}

.decrease{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
.change-button
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.result{
  text-align:center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 45px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="change-button">
  <button class="increase">+</button>
  <input type="text" class="result" disabled="false" value="0"/>
  <button class="decrease">-</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give css to change-button class -

```
.change-button {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Just add float: left; for .increase and .result classes

```css
body{
  font-size:0px;
}
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border:0px solid black;
}

.increase{
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}

.decrease{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}

.result{
  text-align:center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 45px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="change-button">
  <button class="increase">+</button>
  <input type="text" class="result" disabled="false" value="0"/>
  <button class="decrease">-</button>
</div>
```

here its working  https://jsfiddle.net/chandirasekaranid/60afmszx/3/